# How to calculate twisted conjugacy class of $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $\phi : G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism of $G$.Then $x,y \in G $ are said to be conjugates if there exist $z  \in G$ such that $x=zy\phi 
(z^{-1})$. Now I wanted to calculate twisted conjugacy class of $S_4$. So how can I proceed with it

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by twisted conjugacy classes and the rest of your notation? I am not familiar with this terminology.

Comment: What Asvin wrote. Is s3 supposed to be $S_3$, the symmetric group on three letters?

Comment: Good. But, what about the rest? What's a "twisted conjugacy class"? What do you mean by $y=(1,2)$? What do you mean by z and Z and f?

Comment: You need to clean this up: $Z$ is $z$, and presumably $(1,2)$ is what is usually wriiten $(12)$. But you need to specify the automorphism $f:S_3\to S_3$ that you are considering.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: As far as I can see for each automorphism you've got to calculate its twisted conjugacy classes. But until you make some effort yo repair the question, remove the typos, give the definitions (as others have suggested) I don't think anyone will put in the effort to help you.

Comment: @ancientmatjematician done..please help now

Comment: I am not convinced that there is anything clever you can do to solve this - I think you just have to do the calculations. I would suggest you use a computer algebra system such as GAP to help.